# using RewriteCond to ban ip range in a single condition

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is it possible to ban a range of ip's in a single RewriteCond as example, 
if the range is 12.34.50.* to 12.34.100.* would something like this work?

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^12\.34\.50/100\.
```

Answer (score 1):

not a single line but could do something like:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^12\.34\.[5-9][0-9]\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^12\.34\.100\.
```